# CALayers and Audio

Tags: ios, calayer, avaudioplayer

I have a CALayer with an image and I have that animates when I touch it, it works, it's great. What I want to do now is also have a sound clip that plays when you press the same image. I'm finding this tricky because the CALayer is from the UIView Class called BounceView. I created an instance of BounceView on my MainViewController. I apologize if I didn't use correct terminology. Do I need to place my audio code in my MainViewController and then use delegation to allow the BounceView to trigger a method on the MainViewController? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *BounceView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "BounceView.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController 
@synthesize BounceView;
@synthesize audioPlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  //Setup the audio player
  NSURL *noSoundFileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:@"InTheMood" ofType:@"mp3"]];
  self.audioPlayer =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                     initWithContentsOfURL:noSoundFileURL error:nil];

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{  
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)loadView
{
  NSLog(@"loadView");
  // Create a view
  CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  BounceView *v = [[BounceView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

  // Set it as *the* view of this view controller
  [self setView:v];    
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
  //    self.audioPlayer.delegate=self;
  [self.audioPlayer play];
}


@end
```

BounceView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface BounceView : UIView
{
   CALayer *myLayer;  
}

@end
```

BounceView.m
I will provide this code if requested but I don't want to overload code. Here I create new layer open (alloc init), give it size, position, create UIImage, get underlying CGImage & put it on the layer then make sublayer of the view's layer.

Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you also want to play a soundclip in bounceView same on the mainVC am i right?

Comment: I want to play soundclip when I tap/touch layer/image on BounceView.

Comment: put your audio player inside the method where you initiate your layer/image, it should be fine, then make it stop when you need it to start.

Answer (score 0):

Since BounceView is an UIView class not a UIViewController, I would let the playing audio to the MainViewController.